# while loop is not exiting when reading a file through BufferedReader

Tags: java, file-io, java-io

In my application I have client and server programms, whenever server got connection from client the server will send all the available id's from MySQL table to client, for this I have used while loop  to read the contents of file.

I tried the following code:

```
while((a=in.read())!=-1)
```

but my problem when  there is no contents in file to read the while loop is not exiting, it is stopping there itself. How to exit the while loop?

Comment: `in.read()` is a blocking call, it will halt and wait for some input

Comment: `in` is a inputstreamreader which reads from the file

Comment: thanks for you reply ,in is BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

Comment: Why don't you use `BufferedReader` and then you can check for `null`.

Comment: thanks for your reply asif,yes in is a inputstreamreader.

Comment: @Sai Sai, check for `null` not for -1.

Comment: thanks for your reply galore actually a is an integer type

Comment: @Expressions_Galore If he's not getting a -1 from read() he won't get a null from readLine() either. Suggestion is futile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`in.read()` will block till data is available to be read. Refer the API docs http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read()

> This method blocks until input data is available, the end of the
>   stream is detected, or an exception is thrown.

You can do `in.available()` to check if any byte is available to read before doing in.read().

Comment: thanks for your reply bimalesh, i have used in.ready() instead of in.available so it works for me

Comment: ,i have posed my recent question as debugging a socket , in that application i am getting some problem can you please help me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using the `while` loop, rather you should go with threads, which will wait for the input from the socket and when the data is available it will read and then it will send/ process the input found in the stream. Using while and waiting (blocking) your main thread is not a good idea